# What properties from the Shape class are transitionable in KineticJS

Tags: kineticjs

It is not very clear to me what properties from the `Shape` Class are transitionable in the `KineticJS` lib.
Any light shed on the subjective would be very helpful.

Comment: Almost all of the ones listed in the API are transition-able. Any numeric value definitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially I asked the question because I realized I couldn't tween a `Shape`'s `fill` property,

However after a bit of searching I found a quick experiment on [snorkl](http://snorkl.tv/dev/kineticJS/) which opened my eyes to how I could animate it using greensock's renown [TweenMax](http://www.greensock.com/gsap-js/)

So this is what I was able to set up, I'd put it up on jsfiddle for you guys, but I can't be troubled to find the CDN version of TweenMax, and Kinetic.

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'canvasContainer',   //Some div's id on your page
    width: 800,
    height: 600
});

var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

var circle = new Kinetic.Circle({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    radius: 50,
    fill: "#FF0000",
});

layer.add(circle);


TweenMax.to(circle, 1, {
    setX: 100,      //notice the camelType
    setY: 100,      //tweenMax translates setProperty to, circle.Property(tweened value)

    colorProps:{    //if you want to tween colour use colorProps
        setFill: randomRGB()
    }
});

TweenLite.ticker.addEventListener("tick", go);


function go() {
  layer.draw(); //redraws after each calculation
}
```

Hope it helps